# How to query for non-consecutive values?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column of `id`: `1, 3, 4, 9, 10, 11` in the table called `t_mark`

How can I get the non-consecutive range? (e.g. `[1, 3]`, `[4, 9]`)

Comment: Look up "gaps and islands".

Comment: See Lag. Lag() <> n-1

Comment: @Nicole . . . Oracle does not have a data type called "list", so it is unclear what your data really looks like.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I mean a column in the table... I'm still new to Oracle...

Comment: before the edit, the question might be percieved as vertical sequence of numbers, e.g. id column has 1, 3, 4 ... as values for consecutive rows, and Littlefoot & Gordon gave good answers . But now, the question is converted like the one which should be treated with `listagg()` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternatively, using `LEAD` analytic function, along with your *fancy* formatting. `TEST` CTE is what you already have; lines #9 onwards is what you need.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 1  from dual union all
  3     select 3  from dual union all
  4     select 4  from dual union all
  5     select 9  from dual union all
  6     select 10 from dual union all
  7     select 11 from dual
  8    ),
  9  temp as
 10    (select col,
 11            lead(col) over (order by col) lcol
 12     from test
 13    )
 14  select '[' || col ||' - '|| lcol ||']' result
 15  From temp
 16  where lcol - col > 1
 17  order by col;

RESULT
-------------------------------------------------------
[1 - 3]
[4 - 9]

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT: Adjusted so that you shouldn't have to think too much]**

This is what you have:

```
SQL> select * From t_mark;

      M_ID
----------
         1
         3
         4
         9
        10
        11

6 rows selected.
```

This is what you need:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select m_id,
  3            lead(m_id) over (order by m_id) lm_id
  4     from t_mark
  5    )
  6  select '[' || m_id ||' - '|| lm_id ||']' result
  7  From temp
  8  where lm_id - m_id > 1
  9  order by m_id;

RESULT
------------------------------------------------------------------
[1 - 3]
[4 - 9]

SQL>
```

Basically, you should learn how to use a CTE (common table expression, a.k.a. the *with factoring clause*).

Comment: I'm not sure how to put my data in it... There's something wrong here... `SELECT m_id FROM t_mark,  
temp as  
(select m_id,
lead(m_id) over (order by m_id) lid
from t_mark
)
select '[' || m_id ||' - '|| lid ||']' result
From temp
where lid - m_id > 1
order by m_id;`

Comment: I don't know how to formatting the code in the comment... sorry

Comment: I edited my message; have a look, please. I hope it'll be much more clear now.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that by "list" you mean a table with a column, then you can do this with `lag()`:

```
select prev_number, number
from (select t.*, lag(number) over (order by number) as prev_number
      from t
     ) t
where prev_number <> number - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick :

```sql
WITH original_table(number_column) as (select 1  from dual union all
                                       select 3  from dual union all
                                       select 4  from dual union all
                                       select 9  from dual union all
                                       select 10 from dual union all
                                       select 11 from dual),
numbers AS (
    SELECT row_number() over (ORDER BY number_column ASC ) row_num,
           number_column
    FROM original_table
)

SELECT nb1.number_column AS lnumber,
       nb2.number_column AS rnumber

FROM numbers nb1

  INNER JOIN numbers nb2 ON nb1.row_num + 1 = nb2.row_num 
                        AND nb1.number_column + 1 < nb2.number_column
```

Result :

```
| LNUMBER | RNUMBER |
|---------|---------|
| 1       | 3       |
| 4       | 9       |
```

[Link to the dbfiddle for testing](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1c0fe08553507b6a50a7cedd199dad54)

Comment: That's some *mighty trick* as it - currently - doesn't return desired result (or, if it does, it is invisible).

Comment: @Theo: before posting code it's a good idea to test it, for example by creating a [dbfiddle like this one](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=55579b11e17c6e0dd048213efc04e174), to verify that the code you post does what you think it will.

Comment: Sorry guys, it's true I went a bit too fast, just edited my solution, tested it on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1c0fe08553507b6a50a7cedd199dad54) and put the link. Lesson learned.